# AppleScript: Carry on, regardless of errors

Tags: shell, applescript

I have a AppleScript in the following syntax:

```
do shell script "something"
do shell script "something 2"
do shell script "something 3"
```

Let us say that "something 2" gives us an error, and is not beeing executed properly . How do I make AppleScript just carry on to "something 3" regardless of what the result of "something 2" is?

Hope you understood,

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `try`block

```
do shell script "something"
try
    do shell script "something 2"
end try
do shell script "something 3"
```